# Sort directory list by subfolder number

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, find

Is there a fast and smart way in bash (maybe with awk/sed/sort???) to sort the result of a *find* command by number of subfolders in the path and then alphabetically.

I mean something like

```
./a/
./b/
./c/
./a/a/
./a/python-script.py
./a/test.txt
./b/a/
./b/b/
./c/a/
./c/c/
./a/a/a/
./a/a/file.txt
./a/a/t/
...
...
```

I want to take the output of the find command and see first the filenames in the current folder, then the files in the first level of subfolders, then the files in the second level, and so on (if possible sorted alfabetically for each level).

Comment: Get the list of folders, enrich this list with the number of subfolders in each entry, sort the list with two keys: the number of folders and the folder itself and finally, strip the number of subfolders.

Comment: Your result is not sorted according to subfolders. `./a/python-script.py` is in one subfolder while `./a/a/` are two subfolders. Or am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: The trailing slash is misleading. "./a/a" is the first file (and specifically a folder) inside the first "./a" folder. You have understood perfectly my questien and your answer below is exactly what I needed! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `printf` statement in `find` and ask it to return the depth of the file `%d`. Then use `sort` on that and cut to remove the output:

```
$ find . -printf '%d\t%p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2-
```

Comment: Clever. With `cut -f2-` (note the trailing `-`) it would even work for paths containing tabs. Even paths with newlines can be supported by using the (non-standard) `-z` options of `sort` and `cut`.

Comment: @Socowi note that `%p` already converts non standard symbols to a boring `?` But the handling of unusual file/path names is always tricky.

Comment: Didn't know about `%p`'s "quoting" mechanism. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I didn't notice the %d directive in "man find". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is much less elegant than @kvantour's answer, how about the `Schwartzian transform` in `Perl`:

```
find . -print0 | perl -0ne '
    push(@list, $_);
    END {
        @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
        sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] or $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
        map { [$_, tr#/#/#] } @list;
        print join("\n", @sorted), "\n";
    }'
```